# Why isn't FromQuery working in my ASP.Net Core 1.1 controller action

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, request.querystring, asp.net-core-1.1

I am working on an ASP.Net Core 1.1 web API. I have a ServiceTypeCode controller as shown below;

```
[Produces("application/json")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class ServiceTypeCodeController : Controller
{ 
    ...
    ...
    ...


    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string a_query)
    {
        try
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_query))
            {
                OperationResult<List<ServiceTypeCode>, string> result = m_bl.GetAllServiceTypeCodes();
                if (result.Success && result.Result.Count > 0)
                {
                    return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Result));
                }
            } else
            {
                // Deserialize query into dictionary of strings and StringValues 
                var query = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(a_query.ToLower());

                if (query.TryGetValue("mailclasscode", out var mailClassCode))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mailClassCode))
                    {
                        OperationResult<List<ServiceTypeCode>, string> result = m_bl.GetAllServiceTypeCodes(mailClassCode);
                        if (result.Success && result.Result.Count > 0)
                        {
                            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Result));
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (query.TryGetValue("stc", out var stc))
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stc))
                    {
                        OperationResult<ServiceTypeCode, string> result = m_bl.GetServiceTypeCode(stc);
                        if (result.Success)
                        {
                            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result.Result));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return NotFound();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = "An exception occurred while trying to get a list of ServiceTypeCodes from the database.";
            m_logger.LogError(1, ex, msg);
            ApiError error = BuildError("Server Error - Exception", "500", "Get", ex, msg);
            return Ok(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(error));
        }

    }
```

If I use the url ...

```
http://localhost:5000/api/servicetypecodes
```

in PostMan with the GET verb, I get the list of service type codes, as expected. However, If I try to add anything as a query string, such as ...

```
http://localhost:5000/api/servicetypecodes?mailclasscode=fc
```

and set a breakpoint in my code at the

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(a_query))
```

location, the value of a_query is null instead of the expected "mailclasscode=fc"

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: The name of the string variable it is expecting must be the same as the one you are sending: a_query -> mailclasscode

Comment: Terrance - OK, so then if I want to have the user use http://localhost:5000/api/servicetypecodes?mailclasscode=fc or http://localhost:5000/api/servicetypecodes?stc=123, depending on if they are filtering by mailclasscode or stc, then I would need to have
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string mailclasscode, [FromQuery string stc)

is that correct?

Comment: That worked. Thanks Terrance. If you want to post an answer, I would be happy to mark it as correct so that you get credit.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The .Net Core Controller Method's variable names must be the same as what you are sending.**

```
http://localhost:5000/api/servicetypecodes?mailclasscode=fc
```

If using that url to pass data the controller method will have to look like this:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery] string mailclasscode)
{...}
```

Or vice versa.

Good luck - happy coding.

Comment: This still doesn't work for some reason if the controller has the `[ApiController]` attribute

Comment: I believe you can specify `([FromQuery("varname")])`. If that doesn't work something else many be wrong.

Comment: That actually worked! Holy cow, how did you find that? PS I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1

Comment: Documentation from Microsoft on .net-core is pretty good. Also `[FromQuery]` as is should also work. May be worth looking into for you. 

Good luck friend.

Comment: Turns out there's a bug in 2.1 that breaks FromQuery in ApiController and the workaround is to override `Name`.

https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/7712

Comment: Well there you have, atleast .net-core's delivery is pretty quick. I remember there was a bug on identity core that got fixed in like a week, good find nonetheless. Upvoted comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can have the *query string name* differ from the variable name in the method. You have to let .NetCore know how by defining it in code like so (using your variable names):

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "mailclasscode")] string a_query)
{
   ...
}
```

or more generically:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Get([FromQuery(Name = "myQueryStringParamName")] string myCodeParamName)
{
   ...
}
```